# Facebook logout is not Working

Tags: android, facebook, logout

I am working in Android app with Facebook integration but I am getting issue as whenever I try to logout the Facebook is not getting completely logout,

I searched a lot and finally I have used the code as follows:

```
public Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
SessionStore.clear(logoutActivity.this);

try {
    mFacebook.logout(logoutActivity.this);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried the above code but not at all working,the Facebook is not getting complete logout. Could somebody help me out??

Answer (score 0):

This May Will help to you...

```
Activity.mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
                if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                    // User successfully Logged out
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully logged out ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } 
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }               
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

                public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                        Object state) {
                }

                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                }
            });
```

Example below url

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/